# Change HTML value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following piece of code on my website.

`<div class="address2"><div class="placeholder">Address 2</div></div>`

How do I use jQuery to target and change this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try something else, wrap your script in a settimeout, this will execute your script after 2 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(".placeholder").html("<strong>Replace</strong> this text with the existing text"); },2000);
```

Personally I prefer using .html to change all content within an element like a div or table, simple because, if you were to use .text then the added string will not take html code in consideration and add it as normal text, for example.

```
$(".placeholder").html("<strong>Replace</strong> this text with the existing text");
```

Will print: **Replace** this text with the existing text

```
$(".placeholder").text("<strong>Replace</strong> this text with the existing text");

Will print: <strong>Replace</strong> this text with the existing text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

add jquery to your html HEAD

and then create a script tag with some jquery code:

```
// .placeholder is the targeting div with the placeholder class
$(".placeholder").html("Replace this text with the existing text");
```

Comment: I recommend `.text` instead of `.html` unless you want `.html`. It causes new programmers to make way to many XSS errors.

Comment: I prefer using .html, simply because, if you added an image to that div, it'll read the added img tag as text not as a functional tag. and the same applies to if you were to add text to the div where one part had a <strong> tag

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.placeholder').text('Look ma, a changed value');
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Unfortunately, the HTML is being generated automatically by a 3rd party bit of kit. I looked at afterInject, but it doesn't play ball.

Comment: When are you loading this 3rd party kit and when are you loading your script to change the text?

Comment: I load the script to change the text AFTER the 3rd party.

Comment: Is your script parented inside a document ready? try adding the script t the bottom of the html page, just before the closing BODY tag

Comment: Used Blake's code, also moved to before `</body>` - Still no luck :'(
I've contacted the 3rd Party to see if they can help :-)

Comment: I'm starting to think that the 3rd party tool is converting that div into a canvas, and therefor your code has nothing to target. try targeting another element in your page?

Comment: It works great on anything but the 3rd party form :(

Comment: If you are using Chrome, "Right Click" on the element that you want to change and click on "inspect element" what do you see there? Div tags or Canvas Tags?

Comment: It's a `<div>`. It's called 'placeholder' and it's inside a parent div called 'address2'.

Comment: Thats really weird then, I was thinking if it's transformed to a Canvas by the 3rd party tool then that's the problem, but in this case it's still a div, really strange. You can also try something else, wrap your script in a setTimeout(function(){ script },2000); this will execute your script after 2 seconds. this is just to test if it might be a "document ready" issue

Comment: Yay!!!! The Timeout part worked!! Wow, I'd all but given up hope - many thanks for your persistence with this Christopher & everyone else who chipped in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".address2 .placeholder").html("new html content")
```

Comment: I think you mean `".address2 .placeholder"`

Answer (score 0):

proabaly you are looking for something like this

```
$('.placeholder').on('click',function(){
    alert('i am clicked');
})
```

using this you can do on click on that div

or if you want to change text you can use

$('.placeholder').text("new text ")